# Search by content type missing some results

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, content-type

I'm trying to fetch all results by content type. I'm testing this by using this query in search on a site:

```
contentTypeId:0x00000000000000000000* path:https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/test-site
```

With this kind of query I'm able to get almost all results, but I seem to be missing two results. One of the results that are missing in the query above I'm able to fetch by specifying the query even more:

```
contentTypeId:0x00000000000000000000* path:https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/test-site title:dog*
```

Let's say the missing results title was Dog Owners. By making the query like this I'm able to get that result, but this is of course not how I want to do it since I need all results with the same content type in one query.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. If I change the the query to `title:*` the problem is the same. Not getting the Dog Owners results.

Comment: Is it possible that there's a search result limit so that not all results are shown with your first query?

Comment: Possibly. It seems kind of odd tho that there would be a limit of 109 results. Where can I change/see the result limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you see the Search Results, it could perhaps be the trim duplicates? https://www.techmikael.com/2013/12/duplicate-trimming-in-sharepoint-2013.html

Comment: Thank you! This was the problem. I am also using search with PnP-JS, so adding "TrimDuplicates: false" to properties fixed it!